# Не показывает что 0 являеться максимальным значение

Tags: php

Подскажите плиз почему у меня максимальное число не выводит на экран в данном случае это "0" а выводит -500? В интервале 2 элементов! 0 и  -500. Показывает что максимальное число -500 но это не так максимальное число будет 0. Объясните пожалуйста в чем именно подвох? Объясните без кода а объясните словами плиз.

```
$arr = [ 5, 1, 70, 900, 300, 0, -500, -300, -100, 1,];

$n = 2;      
$max = 0; 

$left = 5;
$right = 0;

$right = $n + $left;

for ($i = $left; $i < $right; $i++){

    if ($max < $arr[$i] || $max == 0)
    $max = $arr[$i];
}

echo $max;
```

Answer (score 2):

Что написано, то и происходит: если `$max` равно нулю, то сделать `$max` равным элементу  `$arr[$i]`, который равен -500.

Comment: Прошу вас чуток по разверните ваши слова чтоб более лучше зашли мне в бошку)

Comment: В if есть условие, что если max равно нулю, что сделать max равным проверяемому элементу.

Comment: Убрать условие $max == 0; Но а как же я буду приравнивать к 0?чтоб у меня считались отрицательные числа?

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил в код немного текста, чтобы был понятен принцип. Вот это нужно запустить в какой-нибудь песочнице ([сохраненка](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f668d2fe0cb59043d5f72dd29ef03b8fe17b0644)):

```
<?php
$arr = [ 5, 1, 70, 900, 300, 0, -500, -300, -100, 1,];

$n = 2;      
$max = 0; 

$left = 5;
$right = 0;

$right = $n + $left;

for ($i = $left; $i < $right; $i++){
    echo "Условие по элементу со значением " . $arr[$i] . "\n";
    if ($max < $arr[$i] || $max == 0) {
    $max = $arr[$i];
    echo "Выбрано значение " . $max . "\n";
    }
}
echo "\n\nИТОГ: ";
echo $max;
```

Всему виной условие - `$max < $arr[$i] || $max == 0`
Трактуем, как написано — Если выбранное максимальное значение ($max) МЕНЬШЕ текущего элемента с индектом `$i` или максимальное значение ($max) равно 0 задавать $max равным текущему элементу.

То есть, поскольку предыдущее максимальное значение было выбрано в 0, а следующее в цикле -500 то это подходит под условие и присваивается переменной `$max`.

Предвидя вопрос преподавателя "Как изменить код, чтобы максимальное было выбрано другим" можно сказать:
1. Можно убрать из условия `|| $max == 0`
2. Можно изменить переменную `$n`, что приведет к ответу `-300`
3. Можно изменить переменную `$left`, но тогда результат нужно высчитывать

:)

Удачной сдачи!

Comment: Убрать условие $max == 0; Но а как же я буду приравнивать к 0?чтоб у меня считались отрицательные числа?

Comment: Не совсем понял Вашу идею. Можете описать алгоритм словами?

Comment: Идея в том чтоб Программа выводила  максимальное значение при любом интервале "Диапазоне" каких либо чисел в данном случае это Диапазон в 2 значения а начала с 5 индекса)Вывод положительных и отрицательных числе если таковы есть. В данном случае максимальное число среди 0 и -500 будет "0". Так вот программа написана вроде правильно она считает максимальное число и положительное и отрицательное, но в данном диапазоне 0 считается максимальным числом но вывести на экран его не пойму как .

Comment: Наставник "Сыграл" на том что в данном массиве есть 0.